# JQuery div onChange внутри <a href

Tags: html, jquery, onchange

Я пытаюсь добавить событие click на div, который находится внутри a,
Я не хочу, чтобы событие a href срабатывало при запуске события щелчка

```
    <a href="'.$mobil.'items/'.$row_Recordset1['id'].'">
       <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div onChange="addFavorite('.$row_Recordset1['id'].'); return false;" class="_254kQ" data-marker="item/favorite"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.block').on('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  alert('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="google.com">
  <div class="block">Click</div>
</a>
```